# Gerrit dashboard customization

Tags: gerrit

By default, each Gerrit dashboard provides a table with the following columns:

- Subject
- Status
- Owner
- Project
- Branch
- Updated
- Size
- CR
- V.

It is possible to customize that, i.e to define another set of change fields to be presented in a dashboard?

Comment: It's clearly possible (now), since it is done [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/q/status:open+-is:wip), for Gerrit's own Gerrit dashboard.  Also, my company had done it some time ago, but the change got wiped out in the 3.3.4 to 3.7.3 upgrade we just did.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is with labels.  You introduce new labels by updating the `project.config` file.  You do that by:

```
git clone $repourl
cd $repo
git fetch origin HEAD:refs/meta/config
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

Then, add something like this, which is additive to the inherited project:

```
[access "refs/heads/*"]
   label-FooBar = -1..+1 group Verifiers
[label "FooBar"]
   function = MaxWithBlock
   abbreviation = F
   value = -1 Me no like
   value = 0 No score
   value = +1 Me like
   defaultValue = 0
   copyCondition = changekind:NO_CHANGE
```

Then, commit/push:

```
git commit -a -m "add F column for FooBar"
git push origin HEAD:refs/meta/config
```